# Can a US minor travel by air from the USA to Mexico without a passport?

Tags: passports, us-citizens, mexico, emergencies

The minor has a US passport but it has expired.

She's travelling from the USA to Mexico because there's an emergency. She just renewed the passport last friday, but she needs to get over there ASAP.  Will she be able to leave the US without a problem?

Comment: Is the minor a US citizen?

Comment: yes she is a US citizen

Comment: Unfortunately the quick answer is no. I m on a phone otherwise I'd give you the link. Be prepared to pay a lot of money for an expedited service. I'm sorry for your emergency.

Comment: We did this by driving all the time when I was little  14 years ago but I don't know about now that was before 9/11

Comment: I now agree my answer was incorrect. As I had asked in a comment to my answer, could someone please post a correct answer?

Comment: I's suspect the chief issues would be entering Mexico and re-entering the USA, possibly boarding the plane. Leaving the US appears to be a lot easier than that. (Then again, the few times I left the US as a minor were long enough ago that I don't remember all details.)

Comment: Hey, if you like my answer can you please accept it? It is detailed and I believe correct.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no.

Travel to Mexico by land or sea without a passport is possible if you have a [Passport Card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Passport_Card) , (or other [Western Hemisphere Travel Initiative](http://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/whti-program-background) document) but unfortunately travel on a passport card explicitly excludes international air travel.

From the WHTI site -

> WHTI document requirements for air travel went into effect in January
>   2007. All U.S. citizens and nonimmigrant aliens from Canada, Bermuda, and Mexico departing from or entering the United States from within
>   the Western Hemisphere at air ports of entry are required to present a
>   valid passport (or NEXUS card, if utilizing a NEXUS kiosk when
>   departing from a designated Canadian airport).

For land travel, it says that under 16s that are US citizens can enter the USA with just a birth certificate, but I'm not sure if this applies to entering Mexico!

> U.S. and Canadian citizens under age 16 may present only proof of citizenship, such as a birth certificate or Naturalization Certificate.

Mexico appears to have [additional requirements (spanish-only)](http://www.inm.gob.mx/index.php/page/Preguntas_Frecuentes_POT#respuesta7)  for entry for unaccompanied minors, in any case.

Comment: Your "spanish-only" link only mentions requirements for minors who are Mexican nationals *leaving* the country. I don't see anything on that page about foreign minors entering the country.

Comment: For land travel, no documentation is "necessary" at all to enter Mexico from the USA.  If you enter completely into the country (outside the free trade zone), you should get an entry permit, which would require a passport (although I'm not sure of the actual requirements for a minor), although in practice this is rarely enforced (meaning in my dozens of times entering Mexico, I've never once been asked to present that documentation.)